# Creating a 508 compliant 3 columned SELECT/OPTION solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, section508

I have the following display for a product

[image: DropDown Closed]
[image: Drop Down Open]

It used DIVs and Javascript for that effect. The problem is that solution isn't 508 compliant. I would like to rebuild this using a standard select or something like that, but I cannot think of a way to get the columns.

I have also considered using javascript to make the existing solution 508 compliant, by making it respond to keyboard commands, and I will go that route if I have no other choice.

Is there any way to build this using standard HTML controls?

Comment: That sends me in a new direction. If the hidden select has a tab index, then the user can tab into it and use the keyboard to select. Currently my JS updates the select from the selected div, but i could do it the other way around too, update the divs from the select

Comment: I deleted my suggestion after re-reading your question. I wasn't sure it would lead to a solution. [This has been discussed quite a bit already, though.](https://www.google.com/search?q=select+element+columns+site:stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&sxsrf=ACYBGNTeKXIpv2qIcnfwaxD6Sw1k9s4DKQ:1580247679157&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUv8qsoafnAhUCB50JHaVKAicQrQIoBDAAegQIBRAO&biw=1472&bih=762&dpr=1.25)

Comment: Yeah, I clicked through almost all of those before posting here. I know it isn't possible to add items to Options already.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to use js to make it compliant. There is nothing out of the box that does this, especially with the level of customization you want.

Comment: Would you be able to use a monospaced font? If so I have a JS solution for you that would be standards compliant as it would just be a standard `<select>`. Beyond that we are using a lot of `WAI-ARIA` - let me know and I will post an answer